# 'A book is not always a good book just because it is written by a famous writer.' Is this acceptable?

Tags: expressions, writing-style, narration

When I read the following sentence, I was filled with uneasiness. *Is this construct possible?*

**A book is not always a good book just because it is written by a famous writer.**

The original sentence is found [here](http://seng571213.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-1639.html), which looks like a collection of past exam questions for Japanese high schoolers.

I immediately thought I say:

**It is hard to determine if a book is good just because it was written by a famous author.**

I’m not comfortable of using narratives when the purpose of communication is to give an exposition. The original sentence is in a style of giving a definition of a book, while the speaker is arguing a value of a book.

Comment: Good Q for [writers.se]

Comment: 'Is this construct[ion] possible? asks about the acceptability of the sentence (I've addressed what I believe to be the point at issue).  I've adjusted the title question to match the body question to make your request on-topic, rather than adjusting the body question and then close-voting. Deciding on the appropriateness of using a perfectly grammatical sentence in a given situation is discourse interpretation and off-topic on ELU. Though I can't imagine many would disagree with the claim that 'A book is not always a good book just because it is written by a famous writer.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'A book is not [always] a good book just because it is written by a famous writer.' is fine: grammatical and idiomatic.

[Collins Cobuild](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/just-because) explains this well, though I'd say the expression is *not formal* (ie would be out of place in only the most formal of contexts) rather than *informal*:

> **just because** phrase [informal, spoken]
>
> You use just because when you want to say that a particular situation
>   should not necessarily make you come to a particular conclusion.
>
> *Just because it has a good tune does not mean it is great music.*
>
> *Just because something has always been done a certain way does not make it right.*
>
> ...
>
> *I do not have any rights just because I have been here a long time.* [The Sun (2016)]

[which could have be written, with a slight change in focus]

*Just because a person has been here a long time does not mean they [always / automatically] have rights.*

It is understandable to worry about the possible ambiguity; without the 'always' or 'automatically', 'A book is not a good book ...' and 'I do not have any rights ...' are garden-path lead-ins. But the 'just because ...' is recognised as adjusting the meaning of

'A book is not a good book ...' / 'I do not have any rights ...'

to

'It would be wrong to assume that a book is good ...' / 'It would be wrong to assume that any rights that I have are mine ...'.

.............

But the sentence

*It is hard to determine if a book is good just because it was written by a famous author.*

while an obvious (but unnecessary) attempt to address the surface-level ambiguity, does not work. You need say

*It isn't safe to assume / state that a book is good just because it was written by a famous author.*

Comment: O’oh, it sounds like I’ve been saying it all wrong... but I wonder if anybody actually say what you’re suggesting. Besides, I’d like to use positive in a sentence.